# Python split method removing spaces....why?

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have this doing what I want it to (Take a file, shuffle the middle letters of the words and rejoin them), but for some reason, the spaces are being removed even though I'm asking it to split on spaces. Why is that?

```
import random

File_input= str(input("Enter file name here:"))

text_file=None
try:
    text_file = open(File_input)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print ("Please check file name.")



if text_file:            
    for line in text_file:
        for word in line.split(' '):
            words=list (word)
            Internal = words[1:-1]
            random.shuffle(Internal)
            words[1:-1]=Internal
            Shuffled=' '.join(words)
            print (Shuffled, end='')
```

Comment: This is the nature of `split`. The separator is treated as an unwanted delimiter and discarded.

Comment: So is there a way to keep it in?

Comment: Check out the answer I've provided, it shows two ways depending on which kind of result list you're looking for.

Comment: I also see you are a new user and that this is your first question, so please check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accept the answer that is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the delimiter as part of the values:

```
d = " " #delim
line = "This is a test" #string to split, would be `line` for you
words =  [e+d for e in line.split(d) if e != ""]
```

What this does is split the string, but return the split value plus the delimiter used. Result is still a list, in this case `['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'test ']`.

If you want the delimiter as part of the resultant list, instead of using the regular `str.split()`, you can use `re.split()`. The docs note:

> re.split(pattern, string[, maxsplit=0, flags=0])
>   Split string by the
>   occurrences of pattern. If capturing parentheses are used in pattern,
>   then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part
>   of the resulting list.

So, you could use:

```
import re
re.split("( )", "This is a test")
```

And result:
 `['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'test']`

Comment: Well I thought it worked... Instead of putting a string in the re.split, is there any way to put the variable? Because it doesn't seem re.split works with variables.

Comment: Works fine with variables for me here: http://ideone.com/WvNVuG  If you're having trouble with re.split and can't figure it out with the code I just linked, try making a new question.